# How to convert a string to array and convert each of the hex value in array to decimal in python?

Tags: python

I want the following steps to be implemented in python

1)  string 7f33117cf266a525

2)  uppercase 7F33117CF266A525

3)  Put it in an array [7F,33,11,7C,F2,66,A5,25]

4)  convert it to binary[127,51,17,124,242,102,165,37]

and vice-versa

1)   binary[127,51,17,124,242,102,165,37]

2)   convert to hex [7F,33,11,7C,F2,66,A5,25]

3)   7F33117CF266A525

4)   7f33117cf266a525

```
string="7f33117cf266a525"
print(string.upper())
T=list(string)
T
```

gives an output
['7', 'F', '3', '3', '1', '1', '7', 'C', 'F', '2', '6', '6', 'A', '5', '2', '5']
how to seperate two characters with comma?

Comment: `[string[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(string), 2)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Python 3.5+ you can use the `bytes.fromhex` method to convert hex string to bytes, and use the list constructor to convert bytes into a list of integers:

```
>>> list(bytes.fromhex('7f33117cf266a525'))
[127, 51, 17, 124, 242, 102, 165, 37]
```

And you can use the bytes constructor to convert a list of integers to bytes, and use the `bytes.hex` method to convert bytes to hex string:

```
>>> bytes([127, 51, 17, 124, 242, 102, 165, 37]).hex()
'7f33117cf266a525'
```

Comment: Should mention `python3` only, just incase :)

Comment: Indeed. Updated my answer with the note then.

Answer (score 2):

Try this to separate every two characters in the `string` :

```
T = [string[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(string), 2)]
# T = ['7f', '33', '11', '7c', 'f2', '66', 'a5', '25']
```

However, if you have odd number of characters in `string` and want to get a list of every two characters starting from first, then try this :

```
T = list(map(''.join, zip(*[iter(string)]*2)))
# T = ['7f', '33', '11', '7c', 'f2', '66', 'a5', '25']
```

Difference is, if `string = '7f33117cf266a5251'`, first list comprehension returns `['7f', '33', '11', '7c', 'f2', '66', 'a5', '25', '1']` whereas the second one still returns `['7f', '33', '11', '7c', 'f2', '66', 'a5', '25']`

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't really split it unless, you know the data,

```
>>> string
'7f33117cf266a525'
>>> string.upper()
'7F33117CF266A525'
>>> [ord(x) for x in string.decode('hex')]
[127, 51, 17, 124, 242, 102, 165, 37]
>>> [format(ord(x), 'x') for x in string.decode('hex')]
['7f', '33', '11', '7c', 'f2', '66', 'a5', '25']
```

Answer (score 1):

1) String `"7f33117cf266a525"`

```
string = "7f33117cf266a525"
```

2) Uppercase `"7F33117CF266A525"`

```
string = string.upper()
```

3) Put it in an array `["7F","33","11","7C","F2","66","A5","25"]`

```
string = [string[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(string), 2)]
```

4) Convert it to binary `[127,51,17,124,242,102,165,37]`

```
string = [int(x, 16) for x in string]
```

**vice-versa**

1) Binary `[127,51,17,124,242,102,165,37]`

```
binary = [127,51,17,124,242,102,165,37]
```

2) Convert it to hex `["7F","33","11","7C","F2","66","A5","25"]`

```
binary = [hex(x)[2:] for x in binary]
```

3) String `"7f33117cf266a525"` (it will be already lower-case)

```
binary = "".join(binary)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code might work.

```
def split_by_n(seq, n):
    while seq:
        yield seq[:n]
        seq = seq[n:]


string = input('enter string:') #enter input string
uppercase = string.upper()   #convert to upper case
split = (list(split_by_n(uppercase, 2)))  #split it by 2 characters
converted = [int(i, 16) for i in split]  #convert the base to bin/decimal
print(converted) #display the output


converted_back = [hex(i)[2:] for i in converted]    #convert it back to hex
back_to_string = "".join(converted_back)     #join them to get string
print(back_to_string) #print the output
```